# Using 2 Storyboards for different screen sizes Xcode 5 iOS 7

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, storyboard

I need to create 2 storyboards for my iOS 7 app in Xcode 5. I need a story board for the 4 inch screen and one for the 3.5 inch, because auto layout does not work with this app. I have one titled "iPhone_3.5" and one titled "Main". I put the following code in my AppDelegate.m:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

    if(result.height == 960){
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone_3.5.storyboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];

    }
```

}

But when I launch the app on my iPhone 4, it still shows the iPhone 5 storyboard, and thus looks terrible. Is there something that I'm missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am switching storyboards using storyBoardWithName:bundle same as yours but I didn't include the extension '.storyboard' to the string argument. Maybe you could try that up. Xcode may have trouble finding the storyboard file as a result it loads the default one which the Main.storyboard. Another thing is your equalities. Maybe you could use this instead.

```
if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height>=568) {
       // load iPhone 4 inch storyboard.
} else {
     // load iPhone 3.5 inch storyboard
}
```