# XCode 5: Issue with creating UI interface for 3.5 inch and 4 inch

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I designed UI for iphone 4 inch. When I see the UI in simulator for 3.5 inch, the bottom portion is stripped off. I tried autolayout and constraints only to make my UI much worse.

Is there a solution to ensure that your UI looks the same for 3.5 inch and 4 inch?

Comment: This may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648130/using-2-storyboards-for-different-screen-sizes-xcode-5-ios-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect iphopne 3.5 inch or 4 inch using bellow:

```
#define is_iPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE
```

Check it using bellow method for example:

```
     if (is_iPhone5) {
           // this is iPhone 4 inch
     }  else {

           //iPhone  3.5 inch
     }
```